# Automatically Kill IIS Express Process After Debugging (VS Express 2013 Web)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, iis-express, visual-studio-express

I'm developing an ASP.NET (Razor v2) Web Site in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web, so when I run the site to debug, VS automatically starts up an IIS Express process.

When I stop debugging using the VS "Stop Debugging" button, the IIS Express System Tray and IIS Express Worker Process continue running, even after VS detaches. (And, I suspect, carrying a bad state from one run to the next, but that's a different question entirely.)

Is there a VS option or project setting somewhere that I can set to automatically kill this process once I hit the "Stop Debugging" control in VS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out this isn't possible, since VS 2013 Express doesn't include the "Terminate All" command.  Would need the full version of VS 2013.

Comment: this is a misleading answer, terminate all command exists in VS 2013 and 2015, one just need to turn it on, just like its mentioned in the other answer

Answer (score 19):

Yes, add the `Terminate All` button to your debug toolbar

1. Right click tool bar area
2. select `Customize...` from context menu
3. In Customize dialog select `Commands` tab
4. Select `Toolbar` Radio button
5. From Toolbar Dropdown Select appropriate Toolbar
6. Click `Add Command...` Button
7. From `Add Command` dialog select Debug Category from list
8. Select `Terminate All` from `Commands` list
9. Click OK
10. position `Terminate All` on the button bar using up/down buttons NB: this is a text only button
11. Click Close

Just to clarify - I'm using VS2012 Pro and I'm assuming Terminate All exists in VS2013 Express.  If you can't find it I suggest clicking the Keyboard Button on the `Customize` dialog and search for 'Terminate'

Comment: I don't see that option under "Add Command" -> "Debug" category.  I have "Break All," which I don't think is the same, and the command list jumps straight from "Symbol Path" to "Threads" in alphabetical order.

Comment: I'll add a procedure in my answer - brb

Comment: Looks good, but I still don't see a "Terminate All" option.  Is this a difference between full VS 2013 and Express, maybe? http://i.stack.imgur.com/JXijn.png

Comment: maybe, or maybe because Express versions have a limited command set? I really don't know

Comment: VS2013 Full definitely has the Terminate All command, so it is simply excluded in the Express version.