# SQLite.Interop unable to delete file on clean of solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sqlite, dll

I'm using the Nuget package `System.Data.SQLite` in an MVC web application. There seems to be lock issue when I try to clean the solution and rebuild. The error message I get is:
`Unable to delete file "bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll". Access to the path '\bin\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll' is denied.`

I'm thinking that the database is either still open or that the .dll is still in use, but I can't find any documentation or any reference to the same problem. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028069/unable-to-load-dll-sqlite-interop-dll)  seems like a similar issue but doesn't provide a resolution to my problem.

Here is a code snippet that I'm using to write to the SQLite database:

```
        var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        var debugEntriesTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE ...";

        var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = debugEntriesTableQuery;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
```

Is there another step needed to properly close the connection to the database and inform the dll and the connection has closed?

I am using this code inside a data solution that I have added to a nuget package and am using in another solution. I am only having this problem when building/cleaning the solution that is using my nuget package.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I have found the solution my friend: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22514442/2544235

Answer (score 1):

Killing the IIS Express process solves this error for me as pointed out by the link Eric points to. I am using Visual Studio 2015 community. I exit the IIS Express process from the taskbar.

[image]

[image]