# Unable to delete file "....\SQL.Interop.dll". Access to the path '....\SQLite.Interop.dll' is denied. when trying to clean solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sqlite, dll

I'm using the Nuget package System.Data.SQLite in an MVC desktop application. I get an error when I try to clean the solution. The error message I get is: Unable to delete file "...bin\Debug\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll". Access to the path '\bin\Debug\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll' is denied.

This is nearly the same question that was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175839/sqlite-interop-unable-to-delete-file-on-clean-of-solution), but because I just created my SO account, I am unable to add my comment there.

I am using the NuGet packages System.Data.SQLite and System.Data.SQLite.Core on my database project and System.Data.SQLite.Core on my UI project.

I created a button to Terminate IIS process as suggested in one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43159481/7914283), but since I am unable to build my project, I cannot test if this works.

I was able to clean/ build just fine yesterday.  I wonder whether repeatedly debugging has created this issue.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514397/automatically-kill-iis-express-process-after-debugging-vs-express-2013-web/22514442#22514442) didn't work?

Comment: @DanielShillcock No, it didn't.  But Scott Chamberlain's answer below helped me find the process that was using the dll and I was able to kill that process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something has a handle to that DLL open, if it is not IIS Express it is something else. When I am in that situation I use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) from Microsoft and click the search button and search for the path of the file. I can then click on the search result and end task from inside Process explorer.

Here is a example searching for who has the file `c:\agent\bin\clrjit.dll` open.

[image]

I could then right click on Agent.Listener.exe and do "Kill Process"

For your case you would search for `bin\Debug\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll`

Comment: Scott Chamberlain:  The Process Explorer helped me locate the culprit.  Somehow I had an instance of the desktop application that was running in the background without being visibly open.  Thanks!  I upvoted your answer, but it doesn't show because of my new status.  Thanks again!