# How to close iis when I stop debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, iis-10

when I was using vs13 and iis8 when I stop debugging the iis process is 
killed
I switched recently to vs15 and iis now don't have same behavior in vs15

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 - No IIS Express Response While Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462634/visual-studio-2015-update-1-no-iis-express-response-while-debuging)

May be this topic will help you.

You need to execute `taskkill /f /im iisexpress.exe`