# Visual Studio 2015 not working after first successful debug

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have updated Visual Studio 2015 to the first update. Since then I cannot debug my code twice in a row. It goes like this:

1. I start VS and try to debug. So far OK
2. Change code, build and debug.
3. Try to reach a web but it never loads.

If I close the VS and load the solution again it works or If I do not change code in step 2.

Other thing I noticed is the IIS Express Worker process is consuming most of CPU time.

And apparently the symbols are not loaded (I do not see the messages of DLL loading in the status bar).

This is making my development process very slow and tedious.

The solution is a MVC project under 4.6.1 framework.

Any ideas? Thank you very much!!

Comment: This is going to be a VERY tough question to answer...especially considering all of the different configurations and installs you could have on your machine (software conflicts, lack of available memory, etc). If you were getting a specific error, it might be easier to track down...but even then it would be tough. You may have better luck in a Microsoft support forum, or on Super User.

Answer (score 2):

You should boot Visual Studio into Safe Mode.  To enter safe mode do the following:

1. Open Command Prompt, as Administrator.
2. Enter: `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0`
3. Enter `devenv.exe /safemode`

If Visual Studio does load and debug, then more than likely an extension or an update is the culprit.  This will allow you to also see which updates may have occurred.  The other potential issue would be if your Internet Information System had an issue.

1. Otherwise if your Internet Information System is stuck 'on'.
2. `CTRL + ALT + DELETE`
3. Go to processes, end W3P process.
4. Try to launch and debug inside Visual Studio.

Otherwise, simply try restarting your computer.  We would need more information, as this can occur for an assortment of reasons.

Comment: I did not notice anything different. And I could not find the W3P process.

Comment: @Julen Might be called `IIS (Something, Something)`.

Comment: My mistake. Sorry. Yes. If I terminate the process the IIS responds again.  But it is very very anoying to have to close the process each time I want to debug. Does this shade light for a cleaner solution?

Comment: What do you mean "shade light?"  This problem is often coupled to debugging TypeScript and ReSharper.  So if you disable those, or update better yet.  It should resolve the issue.  Another thing you should ensure "show all files" is enabled, sometimes you can have massive hidden directories that can cause an issue.

Answer (score 1):

@Julen - I have the same issue as you and I have found a work-around.

Add the "Terminate all" button to your toolbar and use it instead of just stopping the debugging. This command kills the IIS Express process.

See how to add it here:
[Automatically Kill IIS Express Process After Debugging (VS Express 2013 Web)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514397/automatically-kill-iis-express-process-after-debugging-vs-express-2013-web)

Answer (score 1):

If your IIS doesn't shut down after stopping the debugger, you could do one of the tricks written in [this blog post](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/27/visual-studio-keep-iis-express-running-site-after-stopping-debugger-in-visual-studio-2012-2013-2015/) - but the opposite way because the article focuses on keeping the debugger on.

Here is the proposed solution 2 - to **check "Enable Edit and Continue"**:

*Similar to VS 2013, if you disable Edit and Continue IIS Express will continue to run when you stop your debug sessions.
Open the menu item Tools/Options, look for the Debugging/General option. Scroll down and uncheck “Enable Edit and Continue”*

[image: Visual Studio Options]

Answer (score 0):

It might be hanging when trying to load external symbols. I had a problem with that before.

To test this theory:

1. Open the Tools menu.
2. Click 'Options'.
3. Find and expand 'Debugging' on the left.
4. In the 'Symbol file (.pdb) locations' list, uncheck everything.
5. Click OK and see if the problem reappears.

Comment: All the locations in the list are unchecked. In fact there is only one element in that list: Microsoft Symbol Server.