# Visual Studio 2019 Debugger only runs once, requires restart to run again

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm building a .net core react app. When starting the application in debug mode, I have no problems the first time I run, but if I stop debugging and attempt to run again, visual studio will stop debugging on its own as the web page is loading.

If I restart my computer, I can debug again, but if I stop and start, I experience the same issue. Restarting Visual Studio works occasionally, but it seems like I need to close out all instances of it, wait a few seconds, relaunch, wait for a few seconds after everything finishes loading, and then it will work (again, only once).

I'm assuming there's a process that isn't shutting down properly and is blocking the debugger from fully starting but I can't seem to find it. I am also running visual studio as Admin. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399839/visual-studio-2015-not-working-after-first-successful-debug

Comment: @chakeda Just went through everything. 1) safemode did not allow me to debug at all. It started and stopped without even a first successful run. 2) there are no W3P processes (or IIS processes) associated with my project. I have a few for some other projects that are on my machine but none for the one that is giving me issues. Even when running in debug there is no W3P process associated with it. 3) Terminate all does not resolve the issue. 4) the suggested edits to the debugging settings did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so it's not a complete answer but I found what seems to be causing the issue. When the debug would fail, the URL briefly changed, showing that chrome was attempting to use the legacy browser support extension. After a bit of googling I learned that this could be caused by enabling "Javascript Debugging for ASP.NET" under Tools>Options>Debugging>General. Disabling this checkbox allows me to run debug without any issues.

Since I don't really care about the javascript debugging, this is a suitable enough answer for me, but if anyone else sees this and knows the answer that would keep javascript debugging enabled, please provide the details in case anyone needs it in the future.

Comment: Only thing that worked for me! Thanks.