# Visual Studio Ctrl+F5 stops working after a while, how to extend the duration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, google-chrome, asp.net-core

I'm coding a ASP.NET Core MVC project. I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (VS Code's dotnet watch run) for check my work on use. It works perfectly fine in like first 10 minutes (I didn't keep time). But after that project stops running even I refresh my web page it can't reach `localhost`.

Does Visual Studio have a time limit on this matter if so how can I change it?

Comment: Check this :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399839/visual-studio-2015-not-working-after-first-successful-debug